# Stored procedure runs much slower than query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which creates a 2x2 table for an odds ratio.  A rudimentary odds ratio table looks like:
[image]

**EDIT** - this query finally did finish and it did return the correct answer after two minutes and 32 separate calls to the function.  I can't see why this is running recursively, any ideas, SO?

```
A - only records that satisfy both thing 1 and thing 2 go here
B - only records that satisfy thing 1 (people with thing 2 CANNOT go here)
C - only records that satisfy thing 2 (people with thing 1 CANNOT go here)
D - people with thing 1 OR thing 2 cannot go here
```

All of the cells in the table will be integers representing a population of people.

I was trying to learn some new syntax and decided to use `intersect` and `except`.  I wanted to make the `thing 1` and `thing 2`s variables so I put the below query into a stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROC Findoddsratio (@diag1 NVARCHAR(5), 
                           @diag2 NVARCHAR(5)) 
AS 
    IF Object_id('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL 
      DROP TABLE #temp 

    CREATE TABLE #temp 
      ( 
         squarenumber CHAR(1), 
         counts       FLOAT 
      ) 

    INSERT INTO #temp 
                (squarenumber, 
                 counts) 
    SELECT * 
    FROM   ( 
           --both + 
           SELECT 'a'                                    AS squareNumber, 
                  Cast(Count(DISTINCT x.counts)AS FLOAT) AS counts 
           FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT ic.patid AS counts 
                   FROM   icdclm AS ic 
                   WHERE  ic.icd LIKE @diag1 
                   INTERSECT 
                   SELECT DISTINCT ic.patid AS counts 
                   FROM   icdclm AS ic 
                   WHERE  ic.icd LIKE @diag2)x 
           UNION 
           --only 1+ 
           SELECT 'b', 
                  Count(DISTINCT x.counts) 
           FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT ic.patid AS counts 
                   FROM   icdclm AS ic 
                   WHERE  ic.icd LIKE @diag1 
                   EXCEPT 
                   SELECT DISTINCT ic.patid AS counts 
                   FROM   icdclm AS ic 
                   WHERE  ic.icd LIKE @diag2)AS x 
           UNION 
           --only 2+ 
           SELECT 'c', 
                  Count(DISTINCT x.counts) 
           FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT ic.patid AS counts 
                   FROM   icdclm AS ic 
                   WHERE  ic.icd LIKE @diag2 
                   EXCEPT 
                   SELECT DISTINCT ic.patid AS counts 
                   FROM   icdclm AS ic 
                   WHERE  ic.icd LIKE @diag1)AS x 
            UNION 
            --both - 
            SELECT 'd', 
                   Count(DISTINCT x.counts) 
            FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT ic.patid AS counts 
                    FROM   icdclm AS ic 
                    EXCEPT 
                    SELECT DISTINCT ic.patid AS counts 
                    FROM   icdclm AS ic 
                    WHERE  ic.icd LIKE @diag2 
                    EXCEPT 
                    SELECT DISTINCT ic.patid AS counts 
                    FROM   icdclm AS ic 
                    WHERE  ic.icd LIKE @diag1) AS x)y 

    --i used a pivot table to make the math work out easier 
    SELECT Round(Cast(( a * d ) / ( b * c ) AS FLOAT), 2) AS OddsRatio 
    FROM   (SELECT [a], 
                   [b], 
                   [c], 
                   [d] 
            FROM   (SELECT [squarenumber], 
                           [counts] 
                    FROM   #temp) p 
                   PIVOT ( Sum(counts) 
                         FOR [squarenumber] IN ([a], 
                                                [b], 
                                                [c], 
                                                [d]) ) AS pvt)t
```

`ICDCLM` is a table with a structure like `patid=int, icd=varchar(5)`

There are ~ one million rows in `ICDCLM`.  When I run this query without making it a stored procedure, it runs in seconds.  If I try to `exec FindsOddsRation 'thing1%','thing2%'`.  It runs and runs, but never returns anything (> 2 minutes).  What could be the difference in the stored procedure taking so long?  SQL Server 2008 R2
fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a883/3)

Comment: I would look up parameter sniffing if I were you

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm using this correctly, but I don't see any long-running queries: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a883/10

Comment: @Shmiddty When I run the SQL without the stored procedure the query takes like 4 seconds.  When I try to execute it with the stored procedure with the two parameters it runs for minutes and never returns anything.  I don't know what's up with it :/

Comment: You're running the same exact SQL that the proc is?  Try updating statistics or recompiling the stored proc.

Comment: @zimdanen went from 2 minutes to 4 seconds with `with recompile`.  and it also decided not to run itself 32 times.

Comment: Added as answer because I like points. >.>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're running the same exact SQL as the stored procedure and the times are that different, your stored procedure is probably relying on metadata that is out of date.  Try updating statistics or recompiling the stored procedure.

Comment: do you have any idea why this thing would run 32 times without `with recompile` and run normally with it?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: Does it still run 32 times after you remove the `WITH RECOMPILE`, now that it's recompiled?

Comment: no, it runs perfectly well.  i did change the like operator to `=` expedite things, though.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: Honestly have no idea. :) Things get screwy sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Before changing the procedure, be sure that the statistics are up to date. Also, check the actual execution plan (.xml doc) of the stored procedure and look for the value of the parameters used to create the plan. Also compare the profiling for the parameters that were sniffed and the actual parameters, if the distribution of values or whatever you are pulling is way too different for those sets, then you can talk about parameter sniffing.

After updating statistics and recompiling the stored procedure, check if the problem continues. You can play with the same set of parameters (the set that was sniffed and the one giving the problem).